# Comparison between different apparatus for measurement of dust

Tags: statistical-significance

My stats knowledge is basic.

The question I have is what methods/test can I use to compare the results of different apparatus measuring the same thing?

We have 1 device which has been used for the past 40 years and it is a bit outdated. We have developed a number of other different devices measuring the same thing and we would like to show that the results obtained from the new apparatus is equivalent to that of the original apparatus.

Comment: For comparison with  gold standard, you may find some methods related to [calibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibration_%28statistics%29#In_regression) of use -- at least it might prove a helpful search term. You might also consider whether *equivalence testing* does something like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a Bland-Altman-Plot. Preprocessing depends on the distribution of the measurement values.  Actually Martin Bland and Douglas Altman published extensively on this topic. Generally the method of choice to compare a new ($new$) method against a reference ($ref$) would be to:

1. Transform the variables to have symmetric distribution (e.g. log-transform if distribution is log-normal)
2. For the plot/statistics: 
    First create new variables
   $$ \bar x=\frac{x_{new} + x_{ref}}2$$ and
   $$ \delta = x_{new} - x_{ref}$$ 
   Then plot $\delta$ against $\bar x$ and for the test regress $\delta$ on $\bar x$ and test whether the the residuals deviate from $0$